# SQL Server 2012 does not allow to restore 20GB database

Tags: sql-server, backup

I've got a 20GB backup of a sql server database and I need to import it into my sql server 2012. But when it starts the imopr process, the following error appears:

```
Error en CREATE DATABASE O ALTER DATABASE. El tamaño de base de datos acumulado superaría el límite de licencia de 4096MB por base de datos.
```

I understand it means I've got a limit to create a database, but how can I increase that limit in order to import my backup?

I'm using Windows Server 2008 (32 bits) and I've got the backup in a folder in the Desktop, so I guess the filesystem can handle it.

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Express Edition only allows up to 10 GB database...

Comment: Are you sure that is even 2012? The limit in the error message is saying  4096MB. That was the limit [pre 2008 R2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx)

Comment: Don't confuse the version of the *client* tools you might be using (like Management Studio) with the version of the database *instance* that you're interacting with.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the case, but because each database is created from model database check if there are no set restriction on the model database.

Also check if you have necessary space available on that drive (I suppose you already check this).

If the limit is 4096 MB may be your filesystem is FAT32. It supports maximum 4GB file size.

Comment: Yes, I created a 100GB virtual hd so disk space is not the problem. Do you know which is the most powerful sql server version? I guess the best one (enterprise, business,...) won't have that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If I execute @@version I get the following line:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86) Jul  9 2008 14:43:34  Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition on Windows NT 6.0 <X86> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
```

As Damien suggested, I think I was confusing the database engine with the client tools. I'm very unexperienced with windows server and sql server :(

As I'm usig a virtual machine for testing reasons, which sql server version would you recommend in order to import the 20GB backup?

Bogdan:
I'm using Windows Server 2008 (32 bits), but I've got the backup in a folder in the Desktop, so I guess it can handle it.

Comment: You ought to *edit* this into your question - unless you feel that it is an *answer* to your question.